# how do you manage a database migration when you have to add a not null unique column to a table?

Tags: database, postgresql, migration

Consider a table like this one (postgresql):

```
create table t1 (
  
  id serial not null primary key,
  code1 int not null,
  company_id int not null
);

create unique index idx1 on t1(code1, company_id);
```

I have to a new column `code2` that will be not null and with a unique index like `idx1`, so the migration could be like:

```
alter table t1 add column code2 int not null;
create unique index idx2 on t1(code2, company_id);
```

The problem is: how do you manage the migration with the data that are already in the table?
You cannot apply this migration neither I can define a default value for the column.

What I was thinking to do is:

- create and execute migration that just add the column without any constraint
- insert the data manually in the column not with a migration
- create and execute another migration that adds the constraints to the column

Is this a good practice or there are other ways?

As migration tool I am using flyway but I think it's the same for every database migration tool.